# Prevent modal dismiss till ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to prevent bootstrap modal from dismissing until a ajax response or even not to dismiss  if response is false,lets say.

Here is the code:
Modal body only:

```
    <div class="modal-body">    
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
    <label for="sharedUser" class="control-label right">Share With:</label>
    <input type="text" name="sharedUser" id="sharedUser"  placeholder="Username to Share">
    <label class="help-block errorLabel fl width100" id="kpiNameError"></label>                                                         </div>
    </div>  </div>
```

here is the script that determine what to do with modal:

```
function shareKpi(kpiId,username){
                var shareUrl = "${createLink(action:'shareKpi',controller:'dashboard')}"
                var msg;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: shareUrl,
                    data: "kpiId="+kpiId+"&sharedUser="+username,
                    success: function(response,textStatus){
                        msg=response;
                     },
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
                });
                return false;
            }
```

What i want is modal not to be dismissed until ajax response.

Actually even i am not clear about the question and this question is open to further edits or suggestions.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can add a callback on the close event (`hide.bs.modal`) triggered by Bootstrap just before the close will be executed.

By keeping a state, you can determine if the modal can be closed or not. It would be maybe a good idea to hide the close icon when users are not allowed to close the modal and show it when ajax succeeds (and visitor is allowed to close).

Here is some sample code that could help you further:

```
var ajaxSucceeded = false;

function shareKpi(kpiId, username){
    var shareUrl = "${createLink(action:'shareKpi',controller:'dashboard')}",
        msg;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: shareUrl,
        data: "kpiId="+kpiId+"&sharedUser="+username,
        success: function(response,textStatus){
            msg = response;
            ajaxSucceeded = true;
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            // show error message
            ajaxSucceeded = false;
        }
    });

    return false;
}

$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    if (!ajaxSucceeded) {
        // prevent closing of modal
        return false;
    }
});
```